# How to compose the next.config.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, static-site

I am trying to add sass support and an webpack image loader for my next application together with support for exported routes. I am having problems with how to compose the config file. I don't understand how the sass plugin gets added to the webpack config, and how to compose and export the `next.config.js` function.

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-unfetch');
var Prismic = require('prismic-javascript');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

var apiEndpoint = 'https://apiendpoint/api/v2';

module.exports =

withSass({
    async exportPathMap() {

  const response = await Prismic.getApi(apiEndpoint)
    .then(function (api) {
      return api.query(
        Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'post')
      );
    })
    .then(
      function (response) {
        return response.results
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong: ', err);
      }
    );

  // tranform the list of posts into a map of pages with the pathname `/post/:id`
  const pages = await response.reduce((pages, post) =>

    Object.assign({}, pages, {
      [`/post/${post.id}`]: {
        page: '/post',
        query: {
          id: post.id
        }
      }
    }), {},

  )


  // combine the map of post pages with the home
  return Object.assign({}, pages, {
    '/': {
      page: '/'
    }
  })
 }
})
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi! have you tried https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but seeing that people are searching for this question I figured that I should post an answer. I would recommend using https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins Its a very simple API and much cleaner. Hope this helps.